# Can't get async code in functional component to behave like class component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I added the code below to App.js (functional component) in a new create-react-app. For some reason, sleep() doesn't add the delay I'm looking for.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function sleep() {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    }
    console.log("sleep start");
    sleep();
    console.log("sleep done");
  }, []);
```

To measure delay, I use the following:

```
console.logCopy = console.log.bind(console);
console.log = function(data) {
  var currentDate = "[" + new Date().toUTCString() + "] ";
  this.logCopy(currentDate, data);
};
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-async-test-90eny?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Similar async code works just fine in a class version of App.js:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("sleep start");
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    console.log("sleep done");
  }
```

Comment: The second example works because your logs are also in the async function, that's the only difference.

Comment: just a trick if you don't know about it, you can use console.time to measure delay: 

console.time('testSpeed');
console.log("some function to calculate time");
console.timeEnd( 'testSpeed');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because useEffect is synchronous, it should be inside the async body, for exemple:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function sleep() {
      console.log("sleep start");
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      console.log("sleep done");
    }
    sleep();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work as far as logging the delay. Is there a way to have the delay show up at the useEffect level, where sleep() is called, similar to how componentDidMount was delayed?

Comment: yes, as described  in comment above use console.time(...) console.timeEnd();, involve both between the area you would like to measure.

Comment: That's a handy trick. I added that to the code, and it shows 0.15ms for sleep() in useEffect. Is there a way to get sleep() to produce the 2 second delay in useEffect?

Comment: it's happen because useEffect is synchronous, if you put console outside the sleep function declaration it will be executed immediately. If you want exacly run time it should envolve exacly the code who is assyncronous. The `await` area.

Comment: Since useEffect itself can't be declared async like componentDidMount, is there any other way to get async code in useEffect to behave like how it did in componentDidMount with my sleep example?

Comment: You are doing exacly correct way, create a async function inside it useEffect and afte that call it inside the same useEffect.

Comment: However, I need a way to wait for the code (in this case sleep()) to finish in useEffect before moving on. Basically, I need a way for it to behave identically to componentDidMount.

Comment: I need sleep() to behave synchronously in useEffect. Right now, it returns right away and the async code finishes 2 seconds later, outside the context of useEffect.

Comment: I found a way to do this (thanks to your help). Inside the async function, I set a state when it's done, and I use that state outside the async code to tell me its ok to move on.

Comment: @Ravi, yes take a look at this example I did for you :). useState hooks is the best case for handling data:

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-shaw-ixhod

Comment: Appreciate the sandbox! I added a similar solution and it works great.